# Using Highcharts.js with odoo

Tags: highcharts, odoo, odoo-12

I would like to use Highcharts in a dashboard for my company, I am using Odoo framework to do so. I've integrated another Js library with Odoo before, I have followed the same steps. In the end, I get the chart but no text, legends or anything else showed. What is the problem?[image]

```
var chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pyramid'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Sales pyramid',
                        x: -50
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                                softConnector: true
                            },
                            center: ['40%', '50%'],
                            width: '80%'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Unique users',
                        data: [
                            ['Website visits', 15654],
                            ['Downloads', 4064],
                            ['Requested price list', 1987],
                            ['Invoice sent', 976],
                            ['Finalized', 846]
                        ]
                    }],

                    responsive: {
                        rules: [{
                            condition: {
                                maxWidth: 500
                            },
                            chartOptions: {
                                plotOptions: {
                                    series: {
                                        dataLabels: {
                                            inside: true
                                        },
                                        center: ['50%', '50%'],
                                        width: '100%'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hi @Koray, Could you share your chart configuration object?

Comment: I have found that labels and the title have aria-hidden = 'true' in HTML but now I don't know how to change that.

Comment: Your options work correctly, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4954/ Maybe some CSS styles from your project overwrite visibility of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the Accessibility module The Highcharts use because aria-hidden comes from that library and it worked.